# Keras RNN input timesteps order

Tags: input, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have a question regarding the LSTM input shap in keras. 
The input shape should be a 3D tensor where the dimensions are:

> batch size, time step, feutures

I want an univariate time series model. The only dimension where the order is important is time step. Lets say my time series looks the following:

```
Data = [[1, 10],[2, 9],[3, 8],[4, 7],[5, 6],[6, 5]]
```

with 2 input features and lets say `timestep = 3`.  Reshaped is my reshaped data:

- `Reshaped(1, :, :) = [[1, 10],[2,9],[3,8]]`
- `Reshaped(1, :, :) = [[3, 8],[2,9],[1,10]]`

**Which of them is correct? The first or the second approach?**

Comment: I know it's been more than a year, but I just wanted to check if you got to a conclusion, because I'm having the same question here.